# DataFlow failed with return code 1 with Airflow DataflowHook.start_python_dataflow

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

And this is my code below.

I am getting the below error, when I run the below code. I am trying to transform gvcf/vcf files in my google cloud storage to bigquery using gcp-variant-transforms api.

[2018-06-06 16:46:42,589] {models.py:1428} INFO - Executing  on 2018-06-06 21:46:34.252526
[2018-06-06 16:46:42,589] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', u'airflow run GcsToBigQuery gcsToBigquery_ID 2018-06-06T21:46:34.252526 --job_id 168 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/GcsToBigQuery.py']
[2018-06-06 16:46:43,204] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-06-06 16:46:43,202] {**init**.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-06-06 16:46:43,284] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-06-06 16:46:43,283] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /apps/airflow/dags/GcsToBigQuery.py
[2018-06-06 16:46:43,853] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-06-06 16:46:43,852] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:111} INFO - Start waiting for DataFlow process to complete.
[2018-06-06 16:46:46,931] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-06-06 16:46:46,930] {GcsToBigQuery.py:48} ERROR - Status : FAIL : gcsToBigquery: Not able to run: **DataFlow failed with return code 1**
[2018-06-06 16:46:46,931] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-06-06 16:46:46,930] {python_operator.py:90} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None

Please help me with this issue. Thanks!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_dataflow_hook import DataFlowHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import logging

default_args = {
    'owner': 'My Name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 6, 6),
    'email': ['MY Email'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('GcsToBigQuery', default_args=default_args,
          description='To move GVCF/VCF files from Google Cloud Storage to Big Query',
          schedule_interval='@once',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 6, 6))

dataflow_py_file = 'gcp_variant_transforms.vcf_to_bq'
PY_OPTIONS = ['-m']

DATAFLOW_OPTIONS_PY = {
    "project": "project-Name",
    "input_pattern": "gs://test-gvcf/1000-genomes.vcf",
    "output_table": "trc-mayo-projectsample:1000genomicsID.1000_genomesSamp",
     "staging_location": "gs://test-gvcf/vcftobq/staging",
     "temp_location": "gs://test-gvcf/vcftobq/temp",
     "job_name": "dataflowstarter25",
     #"setup_file": "./setup.py",
     "runner": "DataflowRunner"
}


def gcsToBigquery():
    try:
        dataflowHook = DataFlowHook(gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_platform_id')
        dataflowHook.start_python_dataflow(task_id='dataflowStarter2_ID', variables=DATAFLOW_OPTIONS_PY,
                                       dataflow=dataflow_py_file, py_options=PY_OPTIONS)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Status : FAIL : gcsToBigquery: Not able to run: " + str(e.message))

gcsToBigquery_task = PythonOperator(task_id='gcsToBigquery_ID',
                                    python_callable=gcsToBigquery,
                                    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be avoided by using the [DataflowPythonOperator](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fapache%2Fincubator-airflow%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fairflow%2Fcontrib%2Foperators%2Fdataflow_operator.py%23L254&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFCe-s63u4IpjTtBgI-D0JH_RMEMg) and installing the `gcp_variant_transforms` API in the cloud instance.

**Command to install the required components:**

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms.git
```

In case someone have this issue as well, you can take a look on this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-composer-discuss/Ycq8OVwMjjk/A-OydsS7AwAJ) where it is described a detailed explanation of the steps that [srikanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272548/srikanth) followed to execute the code successfully.